# How is it possible to create Multi part sections where people can answer or comment or vote on various parts of a page's content as given example?

Tags: plugins, comments, content, comment-form

How is it possible to create Multi part sections where people can answer or comment on various parts of a page's content as given example?

- Using this as a reference example (can attach screenshot if link is not enough) 
  https://www.boredpanda.com/rarely-seen-images/

  - In the linked example, people's **comments/ responses/ up & down voting** mechanisms are there under each part of the items/ pics/ sections in/ of the entire page
  - Typically we/ I see comments sections **ONLY below/ end/ bottom** of a Page or Article (the linked example has it too, but it also has sections in between)
  - Not sure if this was done using WP / Plugins or non WP platform
- I'd like to post a Questionnaire/ RFC type Page/ Article where

  - People can address different parts/ questions/ issues raised in Page/ Article
  - With their comments/ answers that "go into" and "stay with" the relevant sections / parts
- **So..**

  - Was this done using WP + Plugins? Yes/ No?
  - Is it possible to do it via WP + Plugins/ Extensions? Yes/ No?
  - How? Ideas/ Suggestions/ Direction?

**PS**:

- Instead of flagging or negative's please comment for clarification as I've tried to articulate
- Also, not sure what "tags" would make the most sense here?

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm afraid that as it is currently worded, your question is likely to be flagged off-topic because it's broad and requesting overall project direction and recommendations such as plugins. This site focuses on answering more concrete, more specific coding questions rather than overarching project strategy. You may want to try asking this question in another place such as one of the Intermediate or Advanced Facebook groups where plugins and strategy are specifically on topic. More info on what is considered on-topic here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Also, as to the "was this done with WP and plugins" question, you may want to look into browser extensions such as Wappalyzer which try to identify what CMS a website is using, and also learn to view the source of a page. If you confirm that a particular site is using WordPress, most often you can view the source of a page with the functionality you're looking for and see which files in the "wp-content/plugins" folder are being used. Sometimes if you compare that list to a different page without the functionality, you'll see what specific plugin does what you want.

Comment: @WebElaine Can you reword it? I don't mind that - use your discretion. I'd asked about plugins long back so I'm guessing policy has changed. Mainly, is this possible? Natively or will require special plugins? Or not even with that?

Comment: It can't really be reworded to be on-topic. Technically anything is possible, it's a matter of figuring out how; this site focuses on much more specific questions so others can learn from the same type of code, rather than focusing on bigger-picture overall strategies that would tend to vary more widely.